# R- ggplot and corrplot produce very different plots (correlation map/matrix)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, r-corrplot

I have datawide, a pivot table (data_wide2) which I generated using tidyr's spread() for a column and then keeping all the rest (data_wide is used for another script).

Then I resorted the levels of my data according to another variable ('Start'), which accounts for the indexes being untidy (83,35,86, etc.)

I used the following code to produce a correlation matrix with corrplot (which was successful and fit for the figure aside from the labels). This first plot shows two clearly darker squares.

```
heatmap <- function(){
    data_wide2 <- data_wide
    data_wide2$Protein <- reorder(data_wide2$Protein,data_wide2$Start)
    data_wide2 <- data_wide2[order(data_wide2$Start),]
    pre_matrix <- data_wide2[,8:ncol(data_wide2)]
    exp_data <- as.matrix(pre_matrix)

    square <- cor(t(exp_data))
    square <- (corrplot(square, method = "circle"))
    square
    return(corrplot(square, method = "circle")) #plot matrix
    }
    heatmap()
```

[image]

Since my final figure must be part of a `plot_grid`, it had to be a ggplot object. Thus, I searched for tutorials on correlation maps/matrices. When I applied one to my dataset, the plot generated had nothing to do with the one I had before. My intuition is that the data got reshuffled back to the arithmetical order, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
 heatmap <- function(){
    data_wide2 <- data_wide
    data_wide2$Protein <- reorder(data_wide2$Protein,data_wide2$Start)
    data_wide2 <- data_wide2[order(data_wide2$Start),]
    pre_matrix <- data_wide2[,8:ncol(data_wide2)]
    exp_data <- as.matrix(pre_matrix)

    square <- melt(cor(t(exp_data)))

    plot <- ggplot(square,aes(Var1,Var2,fill=value)) + 
        geom_tile() +
        scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-1,1),midpoint=0,low='000000',high='steelblue',space='Lab') +
        #scale_x_reverse(lim=c(97,0))
        scale_y_reverse(lim=c(97,0)) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, size = 12, hjust = 1))

        coord_flip()
    plot
    print(class(plot))
    return(plot)
    }
heatmap()
```

[image]

I tried converting Var1 to a factor, to a character, but neither works.

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding these functions (I replaced the original index for (1:97)):

```
idx <- as.vector(square$Var1[1:97])
    square$Var1 <- sapply(square$Var1,function(x){return(which(idx == x))})
    square$Var2 <- sapply(square$Var2,function(x){return(which(idx == x))})
```

But now I lost the original index of the rows (which was irrelevant nevertheless).

I'll leave this question open so that someone can provide a better and more neat solution.